# while storing contact form 7 values why am getting null values in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have used this following code to insert (contact form7) form's data but in the mysql table the form fields are filled as 'NULL' .

```
function contactform7_before_send_mail( $form_to_DB ) {

global $wpdb;

$form_to_DB = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

if ( $form_to_DB ) {
$formData['posted_data'] = $form_to_DB->get_posted_data();
}

$name =$formData['posted_data']['name'];
$mail =$formData['posted_data']['e_mail'];
echo($name);
print_r($_POST['name']);
$wpdb->insert( 'wp_cf7_test', array( 'name' => $name ,'e_mail' => $mail) );

}
remove_all_filters ('wpcf7_before_send_mail');
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'contactform7_before_send_mail' );
```

Comment: What is the output of `echo($name);` ?

Comment: I did not get any output for that echo statement

Comment: echo this $formData['posted_data']  then this $form_to_DB

Comment: Its echoing nothing. the loader icon of a send button its keep on loading

Answer (score 0):

I read your Question. I am also facing this problem. This code you write is belongs to contact form version 7 3.9.Up to contact form 7 3.9 it is ok.
you used following code. It may be work

```
function contactform7_before_send_mail( $form_to_DB ) {

global $wpdb;

$form_to_DB = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

if ( $form_to_DB ) {
$formData = $form_to_DB->get_posted_data();
}

$name =$formData['name'];
$email =$formData['email'];
$subject=$formData['subject'];
$message=$formData['message'];



//$wpdb->insert( 'wp_cf7_test', array( 'name' => $name ), array( '%s' ) );
    $wpdb->insert( 'wp_cf7_test2', array( 'name' =>             
     $name,'email'=>$email,'subject'=>$subject,'message'=>$message,'file'=>$file,'    date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s') ), array( '%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s') );

}
remove_all_filters ('wpcf7_before_send_mail');
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'contactform7_before_send_mail' );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer kunal . Once i got this work i'll mark it as answer.

Comment: Insertion is not at all taking place by using this coding